# Getting error message while running windows application (C# with sql server) on client machine

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, .net-4.0, setup-deployment, windows

I developed a Windows application in C# and used SQL Server for database.

After that I created a setup of that application and added the following 3 components as prerequisites for the setup (using VS2010):

- SQL Server Compact 3.5 SP2
- SQL Sever 2008 Express
- Microsoft .NET Framework 4(x86 and x64)

and checked the option:

```
Download prerequisites from the same location as my application
```

and built this setup.

When I installed on my client machine then first all prerequisites are getting installed before application installation.

After installing the application, when I tried to run it, it runs well but when there is operation with database then it first displaying a message dialog box with message "Error" only with "OK" button and after pressing OK button everything works fine even database operation is working fine but before every database operation that Error message dialog box is coming.

Please suggest me how to solve this problem.

Comment: try running debug view and SQL profiler to get more details about error. 
Hope your developed application don't have any such code.

Comment: @PawanS : in my pc it is running perfectly in debug view, no error coming in any scenario [may be because in my pc SQL server studio is installed], but in client machine SQL server studio is not installed that's why i am installing some depended component as prerequisite. And i m not aware of SQL profiler.

Comment: download DebugView http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647.aspx and run on client machine and keep it running till error comes. Also check log files if your are generating, verify client machines events.
I feel some component installed in your client machine is not of correct version.